# Dependency injection: What I am taught and why I don't understand that

Tags: angular

I am currently learning myself Angular 2. I found this video which I found particularly helpful in this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CD_5YhJTA

However, with regards to dependency injection, a topic Mosh starts on 36:40, I do not seem to fully understand his arguments.

Namely, he states (at 41:50) that by writing the constructor like this

```
export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;

    constructor (courseService: CourseService) { 
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }
}
```

"we wrote a component that is no longer tightly coupled to the service" (quote).

Now I tried to convince myself that it is, but I cannot see how it is. Indeed, we could create a mock service CourseService for other usages of this class. However, there is explicit reference in the constructor to a method which is defined in the service CourseService. In my mind, this makes it clearly not a reusable (and testable) class in this way.

Wouldn't it make much more sense to write something like

```
constructor (courseService) { 
    this.courses = courseService;
}
```

and then to let us worry about what we pass to the constructor somewhere else. Then, in my mind, we are honestly decoupled from the service.

But am I right? Or am I missing the point here? And also, as I am a novice, but in case that I have a point, perhaps somebody could propose and alternative for writing this class along the lines of my concerns?

Thanks a lot.

Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Piccis answer.

**Hollywood principle** (loose coupling)

The main thing here is similar to the Hollywood principle. "Don't call us, we call you"

If you would use `new Xxx()` in your class it would be **very tight** coupling:

```
export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;

    constructor () { 
        let courseService = new CourseService();
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }
}
```

but with the original code from your question **any class that extends `CourseService`** can be passed in and it is also possible to define how this injected instance should be initialized (see next code snipped below).

**any class that extends `CourseService`** is because of a TypeScript limitation where interfaces are not available at runtime.

In Dart for example it would be **any class that implements `CourseService`**

**configure a dependency**

```
class CourseServiceConfiguration {
  ...
}

class CourseService {
  constructor(private config:CouseServiceConfiguration) {}
  getCourses() { ... }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  CourseServiceConfiguration,
  CourseService]);
```

Would provide an instance of `CourseService` configured with an instance of `CourseServiceConfiguration`.

**Use other key types for DI**

If this is still too tight you can use other keys like `string` or [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OpaqueToken-class.html).

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide('courseService', {useClass: CourseService})]);
```

this way you can inject it like

```
export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;

    constructor (@Inject('courseService') courseService) { 
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }
}
```

but this way you loose type checking and autocompletion support because `courseService` is not types. 
This way would allow you to use interfaces in TypeScript as well

```
export interface CourseService {
  getCourses();
}

export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;

    constructor (@Inject('courseService') courseService:CourseService) { 
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }
}
```

allows you to inject any type that `implements CourseService` and still get static type checking and proper autocompletion.

`OpaqueToken` is similar to a string key but it prevents two keys with colliding strings would still be distinguishable. In `OpaqueToken` the string is only informal.

Answer (score 2):

I think the secret is that you can inject a different implementation of `CourseService` from your main.ts (or whatever file defines your initial bootstrap).

This is an example that could work

```
import {provide}    from 'angular2/core';

import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

import {CourseService} from './course.service';
import {MyCourseService} from '../myImplementation/myCourse.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, 
            [provide(CourseService, {useClass: MyCourseService})]);
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to Angular 2 but my understanding is that Angular 2 has hierarchical injectors, I can certainly see the constructor typing being useful in telling Angular to find the nearest ancestor instance of the injectable to use. There could be benfits in using sub-classes of courseService so you 
can have different behaviour depending on the component context.

More on hierarchical injectors:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 1):

Coupling would assume excessive dependency on Service. I guess it is not the case here since Service has clean interface - `getCourses()`. We could make it even less coupled injecting interface with opaque token like `IService{getCourses()}` and it would make the code complicated and less convinient to use, but...

JavaScript allows us to mock or provide different implementations at runtime without casting errors(duck typing). Check this [article](https://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/testing-angular-2-apps-dependency-injection-and-components/).